# momentJS and two different date formats

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Im getting dates as strings in two different date formats:

Like

Format 1 => 25.03.20 (DD.MM.YY)

Format 2 => 2020-03-25 (YYYY-MM-DD)

I thought for option Nr 1 this: moment(dateString, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").isValid() would be false. But is not, this test with a string in Format 1 is also true.

How can I check if a date is in Format 1 and if it is then make a new string like in Format 2 ?

Comment: You can pass [multiple formats with the strict parameter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/), so `moment(date, ['DD.MM.YY' 'YYYY-MM-DD'], true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a third, `true` parameter to enable strict checking as below:

```js
const dateStr = "25.03.20"
console.log(moment(dateStr, 'DD.MM.YY', true).isValid())
console.log(moment(dateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', true).isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```